# Columns spacing issue

Tags: tables, spacing

[image: table before]

I'm in the middle of a LaTeX battle with table attributes and so far I got to what you see above and the code I post below:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}  {p{1.2cm}p{0.5cm}p{0.9cm}p{1.2cm}p{0.5cm}p{0.9cm}p{0.5cm}p{1.1cm}p{0.5cm}}
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.34,0.58,0.52} categoria & Durata & 2008 & 2009 & 2010 & 2011 & 2012 & Aggregato & Altro \\ 
infocommercio\cite{citaz121} & 3Q & 2.9\% & 21.0\% & 15.0\% & 52.5\% & 2.2\% & 1.5\% & 0.9\% \\
camera commercio\cite{citaz2} & 2Q & 33.1\% & 18.1\% & 28.5\% & 36.9\% & 12.7\% & 24.3\% & 18.4\% \\
Istat\cite{citazistat} & 12Q & 15.19\% & 89.76\% & 77.49\% & 65.76\% & 70.4\% & 84.5\% & .30\% \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Percentuali PET dei GDO lombardi}
\label{tabella_gdo_2}
\end{table}
\end{center}
```

The problem is that I can specify the column width but not the padding, so as you can see there's a lot of wasted space, below I post how I would like the table to look more or less.

[image: table after]

so far I have followed advice from http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables by removing spacing between columns with `{@{}c@{}c@{}}` however the table content squeezes leaving a big space between columns unaltered.
Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X*{8}{@{\hspace{2mm}}p{13mm}}}
    \rowcolor[rgb]{0.34,0.58,0.52} categoria & Durata & 2008 & 2009 & 2010 & 2011 & 2012 & Aggregato & Altro \\ 
    infocommercio[5] & 3Q & 2.9\% & 21.0\% & 15.0\% & 52.5\% & 2.2\% & 1.5\% & 0.9\% \\
    camera commercio[6] & 2Q & 33.1\% & 18.1\% & 28.5\% & 36.9\% & 12.7\% & 24.3\% & 18.4\% \\
    Istat[7] & 12Q & 15.19\% & 89.76\% & 77.49\% & 65.76\% & 70.4\% & 84.5\% & .30\% \\
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{Percentuali PET dei GDO lombardi}
  \label{tabella_gdo_2}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

In the above example, `tabularx` takes a width argument, specified as `\linewidth`. That implies that table will span the width of the text block within the `table` environment. Additionally, for the sake of consistency, each of the 8 columns (2-9) are given a fixed width of `13mm` (using `p{13mm}` and a fixed column gap of `2mm` (using `@{\hspace{2mm}}`). 
It would be possible to use other alignments as well by including the [`array` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array). However, the current MWE seems to provide what you're after.

The table still has some padding (a `\tabcolsep`) on either side. This can also be modified, if needed.

[`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) was used to modify the page margins, since it seems necessary to fit that amount of information horizontally within the text block.

Comment: Thank you Werner, I spent hours and I wouldn't have figured it out.. this tabularx package wasn't mentioned in the latex websites I had searched for..